# Suspending and serializing a running thread

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, pthreads

Does anybody know a mechanism that can capture the state of a running thread and serialize that for further resume?
Is there anything available for the JVM?
How about pthreads?
My main goal is to be able to migrate a running thread to a remote machine.

Comment: The question makes no more sense than to ask to "capture the state of a running program". You can't.

Comment: Serialize a unit of execution?  What?  Migrate.. what?  NO.  You can migrate a work item to a remote machine.  Any such system MUST be thread-agnostic.  Please, please don't try anything like what you are proposing.

Comment: @KerrekSB, every time a process is paged out, the state of a running program is captured and saved so that when it is paged back in, it continues from where it was interrupted.

Answer (score 8):

With the cooperation of that thread, you can do it by any mechanism that thread supports. Without the cooperation of that thread, it is impossible. What happens if that thread holds a lock that your serialize code needs?

What happens if you migrate a running thread that is currently using some kernel resource such as a pipe. Will you migrate that resource?

The right solution to your problem may be to have the thread support a migration mechanism. How you do that depends on precisely what that thread is doing. You'll get answers that are more likely to help you solve your actual problem if you explain precisely what is.

Comment: +1 You could have a thread which has a Socket object which would have to re-opened in the right state on a new machine of a FileInputStream to a file which doesn't exist on the remote machine. Its no possible to move a thread between machines generically, but it is possible to move the work a thread is doing between machines.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is really going to depend on what constitutes the state of the running thread.

If the state is local thread data which allows for the thread state to be copied and saved and then inserted back into a new thread, then the mechanism is basically to just save the state with some kind of a serializable object which is then used to create a new thread with the saved state and to then begin it running.

However if the thread state depends on external objects or entities, the problem is much tougher.  For instance if you have a thread which is acting as a server using TCP and you want to save its state then restart it later, the socket is going to change and the client which was accessing the server thread will know that the server thread stopped communicating for a while.

This means that for any external entities that are depending on the thread, will need to know that the thread is being saved and frozen, they will need to have something that allows them to either fall over to an alternative or to save and freeze themselves, and there will need to be some kind of protocol so that the restarted thread can let the other entities know that it is back in business and its current state.

Also if the thread is depending on some external entities then those entities must be able to deal with the thread being frozen.  There may need to be some kind of a mechanism in place so that the thread can release various resources, whose states are saved, and then when restarted, be able to reclaim those resources or comparable resources and then reset those resources to the saved state.

Comment: Let's face it, never gonna happen.

Comment: @Martin James then how bit-torrentz works? we can shut down machine and when again start in the bit-torrentz starts downloading from where it has left?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move a running JVM from one machine to another, you will most likely not do it by yourself but instead use the [live migration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_migration) functionality of a VM manager.

The VM managers will move entire virtual machines from one physical machine to another without stopping the virtual machine or processes, but it's quite a bit higher level than serializing/deserializing a thread. Since a thread may use resources that are local to the operating system such as file systems or sockets, the whole operating system needs to follow the thread to the other physical machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way that you can send a thread, per se. However, you could use a pattern such as the memento pattern to save the state of your thread.

See these references before continuing so you know the terminology:

- [Memento pattern, oodesign.com](http://www.oodesign.com/memento-pattern.html)
- [Memento pattern, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

Basically, you'll have this:

1. Design a job (thread) that can run with any starting state, including a state from mid-execution.
2. When it needs migrated, get the state of that thread.

   - In Java, you could use `ThreadLocal` variables to store the thread state.
3. Serialize that state to the other machine.
4. Use the state to start a new thread with the state you deserialized.

This is a better approach then actually migrating a thread, its state, stack, etc. since you can pick and choose what absolutely needs to be moved instead of moving everything no matter what.

Comment: ' migrating a thread, its state, stack, etc' - anyone, anywhere, on any system, for any reason ever got close to doing anything so...